# How to use lightGBM in multi-classification problem whose target has multi-labels

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, lightgbm

I get a multi-class classification problem that the samples can have more than one labels. So I want to know how to use `lightGBM` in such multi-class classification problems.
For examples, the target is as follows:

```
  id label1 label2 label3 label4 label5
0 0  1      1      0      0      0
1 1  0      1      0      0      0
2 2  1      0      0      0      0
3 3  0      0      0      0      0
```

And I have checked the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/examples/python-guide) of `lightGBM` but it doesn't offer what I want.
So I am wondering how to use `lightGBM` in such multi-class classification problems.